# how to use a variable with extra commands inside a grep function

Tags: bash, for-loop, grep

i have a list of ip addresses which i then read in a for loop
example:

```
for i in $(eval echo "{1..$ip_count}")
    do
      echo $ip |sed -n ${i}p
    done
```

however, i now want to use each ip address as a grep parameter inside that for-loop

I tired:

```
avahi-browse -rvpc | grep $($ip |sed -n ${i}p)
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: How are you populating `$ip`?

Comment: Btw.: I suggest to replace `for i in $(eval echo "{1..$ip_count}")` with `for ((i=1; i<=$ip_count; i++))`.

Comment: [tag:bash] -  "For shell scripts with syntax or other errors, please check them at https://shellcheck.net before posting them here.". Also please read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes before writing any other shell code.

Answer (score 1):

Your `ip` variable apparently contains a string of several IP addresses separated by newline characters. Instead of looping over numeric indexes you could loop over its content:

```
while read -r i; do
  avahi-browse -rvpc | grep -F "$i"
done <<< "$ip"
```

The loop iterates over the lines of `"$ip"` with the current line  assigned to variable `i`. Note the `-F` option of `grep` to consider `"$i"` as a fixed string, not a regular expression. This is needed because IPv4 addresses contain periods and by default `grep` considers "*patterns*" as regular expressions in which a period matches any character. So `grep "1.2.3.4"`, for instance, matches `1a2b3c4d`, which is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in a single `grep` command without any loop using process substitution with `grep -f` option:

```bash
avahi-browse -rvpc | grep -Ff <(echo "$ip") -
```

Make sure you are using `bash` when trying this command as *process substitution* requires `bash`.